# Why isn't web2py more readily adopted?

Tags: python, django, web2py

I have been playing with python and different web frameworks.  I started with Django, but am not in so deep that I am entrenched.  I really quite like python but have not found that "perfect" web solution.

My qualifications of perfect would be:

- simple to learn/code
- simple to host (my webhost, Site5, isn't exactly python-friendly)
- widely supported/used

Web2Py seems like it might fit.  [Their case against simplicity](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_vs_others.pdf) is solid and it seems pretty simple to fire up an webserver (though the quest for a python-friendly web host continues).  And Web2Py does not seem to be widely used.  But why not?

*Tangents:*
Which framework do you use and why?
Who do you use for your python web hosting?

Comment: Perhaps this was true when the question was asked. I am not sure this is true any longer true. Django and Zope is still more widely adopted but they had about 4-5 years of head start. web2py is a solid third and growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is more widely used, because Django is (already) more widely used.

Comment: To understand recursion, you first have to understand recursion